# Returns the character in the "Editable" Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletebox

There Spannable text input field (AutoCompleteBox). For it is necessary to change the text. To do so:

```
{
    Editable editable = getText();
    editable.replace(start, end, "");
}
```

As a result, the text is removed, but when you enter any characters, the text is returned to the end of the input field.
I tried to add TextWatcher, as a result:

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    //Here the text is correct, delete the character to
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //And here is the text is not correct. The cut line is added at the end
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //As in onTextChanged
}
```

It appears not everywhere, yet only seen on tablets Samsung with Android 4.1.2. Why is this happening and what to do?

Comment: is it only me? i do not understand your requirement